# Why registered service does not working in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created service in `app/services/SubscriptionService.php`

then import it into controller
use `App\Services\SubscriptionService;`

and then in controller

```
public function subscribeIt(SubscriptionService $SubscriptionService, Request $request){
  $response = $SubscriptionService->subscribeIt($request);
  ...
}
```

But in result of execution I am getting `Class App\Services\SubscriptionService does not exist`
Do I need to register it in provider ?
This is in provider

```
public function register()
    {
        //
        $this->app->bind('App\Services\SubscriptionService', function ($app)    {
          return new SubscriptionService();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that PHP namespaces are case-sensitive. Also, use `::class` operator whenever possible.

As for code, change this

```php
$this->app->bind('App\Services\SubscriptionService', function ($app)    {
    return new SubscriptionService();
});
```

to this

```php
$this->app->bind(\App\Services\SubscriptionService::class, function ($app)    {
    return new SubscriptionService();
});
```

**Sidenote:** if you are not importing the class globally, you need to prepend a backslash to the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you created the service in `app/services/SubscriptionService.php`.

As Laravel is using PSR-4 autoloading via composer, it is expecting the `services` directory to be capitalised.

Rename the folder to include a capital `S` so it should go from `app/services/SubscriptionService.php` to `app/Services/SubscriptionService.php`.